# java xor over a single byte with a byte[] size key

Tags: java, android, encryption, ascii, xor

I want to apply xor on each byte separately and store them in a specific byte in a certain memory location.

For example I have a string "0", I'm converting it to ASCII and then need to apply xor on it with a multi-byte key e.g "243", the resulting data must be in a single byte. Is this even possible?

```
private byte[] xorWithKey(byte[] a, byte[] key) {
    byte[] out = new byte[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        out[i] = (byte) (a[i] ^ key[i%key.length]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Right now I'm using this snippet which takes bytes array and returns a byte array, this is working fine, but I want to achieve this on a single byte like:

```
private byte xorWithKey(byte a, byte[] key)
```

Comment: Without `i` you just as well could have one single byte `key[0] ^ ... ^ key[key.length -1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of keys and can encrypt an input `byte` with many number of keys based upon your choice of choosing keys from array.

You can use below approach if you want to encrypt input `byte` with all the keys present in array, where encryption function uses all keys for encryption by taking xor iteratively

```
private byte xorWithKey(byte a, byte[] key) {
byte out=a;
for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    out = (byte) (out ^ key[i]);
}
return out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used this approach, but the issue I'm having now with this is that 

Previously with a byte array in the xorWithKeyFunction as an input, I was easily be able to get back the ASCII value and then convert it back to UTF-8. But now I get the ASCII value back but when I try to convert it back to UTF-8 to get the input value "0" it still returns the ASCII value "48" 

Any solutons? As Byte.toString() does not take the Charset parameters and new String() does not take a single byte returned from the xor as an input, it takes a byte array.

Comment: Got the solution, Thanks for your help. Handled this by converting a single byte to a new byte[]